# how to parse json inside a json in angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to parse the JSON file in angular2 but do not know how.

user.service.ts

```
getInfo(): Observable<any>{
  let url= 'example.json';
  return this.http.get(url, options)
                  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                  .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'retriving data failed'));
}
```

user.component.ts

```
template: `<p>{{userInfoes.user_info.user_id}}</p>`

export class USER{
 getInfo(): void{

    this.userService.getInfo().subscribe(userInfoes =>this.userInfoes= userInfoes);
}}
```

example.json

```
{
  "task": "angular2",
  "user_info": {"user_id": "yeehaah", "user_location": "canada"}
}
```

So in the example json file. the property is another json. When we use map to parse the json file, it only parse once and leave user_info property a string (json). The **parsed example.json** explains what I meant by leaving another json.

parsed example.json

```
{
  task: "angular2",
  user_info: {"user_id": "yeehaah", "user_location": "canada"}
}
```

If I want to display `user_id` inside the `user_info` property in the example.json file, what should I do ?

Comment: What do you mean by "another json"?  These are *javascript objects*, so once you parse the JSON of the entire payload, those will be accessible without further parsing.  Example: `var id = user_info.user_id` or `var id = user_info['user_id]`

Comment: I used `console.log(user_info.user_id)`, it says it's undefined tho..

Comment: There's no magic to parsing JSON. Use `JSON.parse` and it will return the parsed JSON.

Comment: @BogdanM. In angular2?

Comment: @BogdanM. it works Bogdan !

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be quotes around the properties: `user_id`, `user_location`. If you fix this, the json should parse correctly so that `user_info.user_id=="yeehaah"`.

Comment: Hi, Bryant, do you mean in the orginal file **example.json**?

Comment: Yes, the json you're passing in doesn't look like its properly formatted to begin with

Comment: Thanks!! Bryant :)

Comment: No worries, just let me know if that fixes your issue :)

Comment: It does not work.. without quotes around the properties, it is not taken as a json file.. [link](http://jsonlint.com/) try this

Comment: My apologies, bogdan is correct, `JSON.parse( json_string );` will produce usable results. When generating an object in javascript you don't use the quotes. JSON does use the quotes.